# Split more than one word in python

Tags: python, split

How can I write a program in python that can split more than one word or character?
For example I have these sentences: `Hi, This is a test. Are you surprised?` In this example i need my program to split these sentences by ',','!','?' and '.'. I know split in `str` library and `NLTK` but I need to know is there any internal pythonic way like split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use re.split:

```
string = 'Hi, This is a test. Are you surprised?'
words = re.split('[,!?.]', string)
print(words)
[u'Hi', u' This is a test', u' Are you surprised', u'']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `tokenize` function of [NLTK](http://nltk.org/install.html) package. `NLTK` stands for *Natural Language Tool Kit*

Or try `re.split` from `re` module.

From [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) doc.

```
>>> re.split('\W+', 'Words, words, words.')
['Words', 'words', 'words', '']
>>> re.split('(\W+)', 'Words, words, words.')
['Words', ', ', 'words', ', ', 'words', '.', '']
>>> re.split('\W+', 'Words, words, words.', 1)
['Words', 'words, words.']
>>> re.split('[a-f]+', '0a3B9', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
['0', '3', '9']
```

Comment: Something like that but I don't want to use NLTK.

Comment: Well you can also split using regular exp.

Comment: I think I'm asking how?!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a tricky way for my question. I don't need to use any modules for that. I can use `replace` method of str library and replace words like `!` or `?` with `.` . Then I can use `split` method for my text to split word by `.` .

Comment: Why is this better than the answers provided?

Comment: @HerrActress Not better but it's a way doesn't need any modules.

Comment: For this you should call str.replace() for each special symbol !, ?, ... If you want to replace by one call - you should use regexp re.sub().

Comment: @AndreyShokhin  No offence but I could use mapping for this problem. And thanks for your good answer.

Comment: Or you doesn't want import anything because you are fighting for performance?

Comment: @AndreyShokhin Sorry but I didn't get what you mean. You mean python program performance or myself?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43838/discussion-between-hamid-fzm-and-andrey-shokhin)

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_words(s):
    l = []
    w = ''
    for c in s:
        if c in '-!?,. ':
            if w != '': 
                l.append(w)
            w = ''
        else:
            w = w + c
    if w != '': 
        l.append(w)
    return l



>>> s = "Hi, This is a test. Are you surprised?"
>>> print get_words(s)
['Hi', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'Are', 'you', 'surprised']


If you change '-!?,. ' into '-!?,.'
The output will be:
['Hi', ' This is a test', ' Are you surprised']
```

Comment: Good but not suitable for large texts!